# How to expand group variable using UI variable?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have three build pipelines, one for each environment: `Dev`, `QA`, `Prod`. I've defined group variables for each environment - `group-Dev`, `group-QA`, `group-Prod`.  Each build pipeline has a variable `TestEnvironment` set to its respective environment. I am trying to expand the group variable name using the pipeline variable but I cannot get it to work.  At compile time it cannot evaluate the group variable name, I assume because it doesn't know the runtime variable value yet.

What I want is something like this:

```
variables:
  env: $(TestEnvironment)

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job: TestVariable
    variables:
      - group: 'group-${{variables.env}}'
    steps:
    - script: echo $(TestEnvironment), $(Database.Name), ${{variables.env}}
      displayName: 'Printing the variable'
```

But the only way i can get it to work is if I hard-code the variable, ie: `env: QA`.  I also tried removing `variables` section and setting `group: 'group-$(TestEnvironment)`, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported today. You need to declare the variable group you want to consume in a YAML pipeline. Please check the following issue:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3702

Comment: The link had some ideas like using expressions/script which helped me work around the issue. Not elegant but it works.